# Issue with domain access in Japan

Tags: networking

I'm having an issue with a clients domain, which for some reason cannot be accessed by their clients in Japan.

There doesn't seem to be any issue accessing the site from other countries, and the client in Japan has tried on several devices and varying networks with no success. They can access the site via a US proxy, and also (which i don't understand) via a Japanese Web Proxy.

The error reported by the clients client is ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

The clients client is able to access other sites on the same server, but the particular website in question. And there are no georestrictions in place.

Has anyone had a similar issue which with they may be able to shed any light on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The error reported by the clients client is ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

You need to get better information from an affected device - to find out exactly what is redirecting and where.

Normally redirects should only arise on the origin server - but in this day there are a lot of people who think that they know better than the people who designed HTTP and sell products labelled as "Security".

If the site is not using TLS, then start using it. It reduces (but does not eliminate) the ability of third parties to interfere with your traffic.

Also, check how many redirects you get when accessing the site locally - and start investigating where and why they are happenning.